# elasticsearch 2.2.x not supported with cgroups v2

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, linux-kernel, cgroups

Elasticsearch < 5.2.x has a bug that prevents it to work with Linux kernel > 4.5 since cgroup v2 introduction
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt

it will not be fixed since it is fixed in a newer version:

> The bug report is against version 5.2.2 so I see it as "won't fix" for branch 5.2.x.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23486

Since the problem consists in having cgroup v2 in `/proc/self/cgroup` for elasticsearch, and it should be possible to run cgroup v1 and v2 in same machine, does anyone know a way to "force" elasticsearch into cgroup v1 so as to let it run with kernel 5.2 (not using virtualbox/vmware)?